# How can I use pandas.groupby.agg() for subcolumns?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I would like to group this dataframe by equipment 2 `EQ2` and compute the mean and standard deviation of the subcolumn `['A']['mean']` (i.e. the mean of the mean and the std of the mean)

```
>>> df2
   EQ EQ2         A
               mean       std
0  a1  b1 -0.875496  0.532141
1  a2  b1  0.764438  0.315518

>>> df3 = df2.groupby(['EQ2']).agg({'A','mean': ['mean', 'std']}).reset.index()
```

Comment: How is created `df2` ?

Comment: The matrix `df2` was just a simplification. I obtained it by introducing random values and grouping them first with respect to `EQ`. That is why you see a mean and std column. The matrix I wanted to obtain is `df3` as you can see below. 

In my real data, I had to group a number of acquisitions and later group each of these parameters according to the equipment used.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, in case anyone finds it useful:

```
>>> df3 = df2.groupby(['EQ2']).agg({('A','mean') : ['mean','std']}).reset_index()
>>> df3
  EQ2         A
           mean
           mean       std
0  b1 -0.055529  1.159608
```